# Why dose lldb source-map not working on windows

Tags: windows, debugging, lldb

I'm using `lldb-server` on linux:

```sh
lldb-server platform --listen "*:1234" --server
```

And using `lldb.exe` on `windows` to connect to it:

```sh
./lldb.exe
(lldb) platform select remote-linux
(lldb) platform connect connect://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1234
(lldb) settings set target.source-map {src} {dst}
(lldb) target create a.out
```

Execute, add/remove breakpoints, callstack all work well, **but I can't see the source code**

I tried to use `lldb` on another `Linux` machine to connect to the same lldb-server, the source map works well.

#### So my question is:

1. Did I miss any configurations?
2. Or is there any limitation on this kind of usage?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This task requires that lldb cut the tail end from a Linux path and append it to a Windows path root.  I would not be entirely surprised if lldb flubs that one.  If you have the inclination, you might file a bug about this with http://bugs.llvm.org.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply, I think you are right, and I'll build a debug version to confirm that. Thanks again !

Comment: @JimIngham , it is a bug in lldb and I've fixed it in https://reviews.llvm.org/rGfe19ae352ce201e7bab8baac4587cc4334e742e4

Comment: I saw that, thanks!